# I need to write a single script in which I have to execute a certain set of commands as oracle user and some as root,how to do it?

Tags: sudo

I need to write a single script in which I have to execute a certain set of commands as oracle user, then become root user and execute a few commands and and then back to oracle user. All of this has to be done in a single script...how to do this?
To be more specific, I am basically automating OTD(Oracle Traffic Director) installation and configuration for which I have been asked to write a shell script. All the steps in its installation are done as oracle user, but these two commands:

chown root portbind

chmod 4750 portbind

have to be executed after becoming a root user, the further steps of automation have to be done as oracle user again. So I need a way to switch users(root and oracle) in my script.

Comment: Welcome to U&L StackExchange. We're not a script-writing service. There are many tutorials to help you learn to script available on the web. There are also many people out there who will offer professional consulting services to help you do this. If you decide to take the do it yourself route that's great, and you'd be welcome to ask specific questions here when and if you get stuck.

Comment: Both answers should solve your original question, did you actually try the methods in them before you edited it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the script as root and for the commands that you need to be executed as another user, use the `-u` switch of sudo. Consult the manual page of sudo with [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/en/man8/sudo.8.html).

```
# sudo -u user echo test
test
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the script as the oracle user.  In your script, for the parts that require root privileges, use `sudo` as you would on the command line.  e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'This command is echoed by oracle user'
sudo echo 'This command is echoed with superuser privileges'
```

Then, configure the sudoers file (via `visudo`) to ensure that the specific commands required to be run can be run without requiring a password.  Add the following line towards the bottom of the file and change the command as required - you'll want one of these lines for every command you want to run with `sudo`

```
oracle localhost = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/command
```